# Mapbox add layer with vector source

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a vector source(tileset) uploaded on mapbox studio. I am adding a source with this tileset like :

```js
map.addSource("abc", {
            type: "vector",
            url: "mapbox://RELEVANT_MAP_ID"
        });
```

then I am trying to add a layer like:

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "layer_id",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "abc",
    "source-layer": "source_layer_id",
    "layout": {
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
    },
    "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ff69b4",
        "line-width": 4
    }
});
```

When I execute this code I get an error :

```
Error: Source layer "source_layer_id" does not exist on source "abc" as specified by style layer "terrain-data"
```

What exactly the source_layer is for ? How do I mention the source layer on source in case of vector tiles ? Is there any way to mention the source layer while creating the tile set?

Comment: I can't answer your last question as it depends which process you used to create the Tileset (uploading to Mapbox Studio, Tippecanoe, exporting a a Dataset to a Tileset or something else).

Answer (score 2):

If you open your tileset (the one refereced by your RELEVANT_MAP_ID) in Mapbox Studio you'll see something like this

[image]

The `source-layer` is which layer within that Tileset source you want to create the Style Layer for, so from the screenshot it could be `admin`, `aeroway`, `airport_label`, etc.

Comment: If I want to serve the tiles from my own server, how do I assign the source layer then ?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details about what you setup is on the server side. If you're serving an MBTiles file created with Tippecanoe, the layername was defined by -l or -L, see https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#input-files-and-layer-names